# What are some simple examples of adaptive inflation rate?

Tags: economics, inflation

---

For example what would the interest rate be for a baker with 6,000 XTZ if 75% of tez holders delegate and only 10% are bakers and no stakers?

In this situation what would a delegator with 1,000 XTX earn per annum?

How would these numbers change if half of the baker's bonds were held by stakers?

Answer (score 1):

0%, interest rates are earned in return for loans, but not loan is taking place when a baker creates blocks.

This matters, the industry's tolerance of imprecise language is routinely being used by bad actors against it, don't give them ammo.

As to the substance of the question, there is missing information. What fraction of tez are staked, what fraction are delegated without being staked, and for how long as it been the case?

Adaptive issuance ... adapts to encourage 50% staking. As long as less than 48% is staked, issuance will increase until it reaches a maximum value, as long as more than 52% is staked it will keep diminishing until it hits a minimum value.